# jQuery toggle - change background position of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a jQuery toggle function which works fine: If I click on the dt-tag the dd section slides up or down. Just like it supposed to.
But now I want to extend the toggle function: A background image of a span element within the dt-tag supposed to change position everytime you click on the dt-tag (display arrow up or down). I tried to accomplish that with following code, but I can't get it to work

```
         <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?><span id="cpl"></span></dt>
         <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>


        jQuery('dd').hide();
        jQuery('dt').click(function() {
            var toggle = jQuery(this).nextUntil('dt');
            toggle.slideToggle();
            jQuery('dd').not(toggle).slideUp();
            jQuery('#cpl').toggleClass('clicked');
        });

       #cpl {
         width: 90px;
         height: 11px;
         display: inline-block;
         margin: 0 0 0 10px;
         background:transparent url('../images/arrow.gif') no-repeat;
         background-position: 0 0;
       }

       #cpl.clicked {
         background-position: 0 -15px;
       }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/8xqsx44b/

Comment: Please describe what "I can't get it to work" means. What is happening on the screen? Is the background not appearing at all? Does the background not change position when you click? Are there error messages in the console?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I see the issue now: The problem is that I have multiple dt and dd elements on this page so the span id (#cpl) isn't unique anymore. Thats why it isn't working for me. I tried to solve this by using find('span') or toggle.children('span') but it doesn't work for me. Any ideas how I can address the span in the dt element without using #id? Thank you!

Comment: "isn't working for me" means the image is not switching because the class "clicked" will not be "applied" to the span element. Thank you

Comment: Try: `jQuery('span', this).toggleClass('clicked');`instead. And: ID's must be unique. Use `class="cpl"` for the spans and `.cpl / .cpl.clicked` in your CSS.

Comment: Awesome! jQuery('span', this).toggleClass('clicked') works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps: 1) Give your spans a common class instead of an ID:

```
<span class="cpl"></span>
```

2) Change the last line inside your click-function to:

```
jQuery('dt').click(function() {
    /* your code */
    // this selects only an element with class 'cpl' inside the clicked element
    jQuery('.cpl', this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

3) Change your CSS to address the class 'cpl':

```
.cpl { ... }
.cpl.clicked { ... }
```

[DEMO with three 'dt'](http://jsfiddle.net/8xqsx44b/15/).